# How can optimize this VIEW Statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, view, query-optimization

I have a `VIEW` which is SLOW. I don't like the VIEW Statements as there are lot of `JOINS` and `UNION`.

Here is the view statement.

```
Create VIEW NewView AS

SELECT t2.* FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2
ON t1.Column1 = t2.Column1 AND t1.Column2 = t2.Column2
WHERE t1.Column3 !='String'

UNION

SELECT t1.*, 'Add this string to the Last Column' FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
ON t1.Column1 = t2.Column1 AND t1.Column2 = t2.Column2
WHERE t2.Column1 is null OR t1.Column3 ='String'
ORDER BY Column 4
```

Basically the idea is if a record exists in `Table1` and `Table2`, the record from `Table2` should overlay the record from `Table1`. How can I optimize this?

I have a primary key `id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` in both the tables but I am not sure how I can integrate that with the view. I want the view to have a primary key or composite key. I cannot use other columns as all the columns can have null and duplicate values.

Comment: Do you need `ORDER BY` in a `VIEW`?

Comment: I don't know that I'd classify one `UNION` and two `JOIN`s as "lots"

Comment: I do need the ORDER BY in the view itself. If not I have to do ORDER BY in each query that gets data from the view(frond end). That's the default display I want.

Comment: A lot in the sense that it's slow. Poor choice of words.

Comment: Ordering the View won't *guarantee* the order in the final results.  You will still need to do `SELECT * FROM view ORDER BY x`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join and compare, using an outer join, then use COALESCE to prefer T2 to T1.

To retain a unique key, and assuming your ID's are all positive, you can make one table's id's negative.

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(t2.id,     -t1.id)      AS id,
  COALESCE(t2.Column1, t1.Column1) AS Column1,
  COALESCE(t2.Column2, t1.Column2) AS Column2
FROM
  Table1          AS t1
FULL OUTER JOIN
  Table2          AS t2
    ON  t1.Column1 = t2.Column2
    AND t1.Column2 = t2.Column2
WHERE
  COALESCE(t2.Column3, t1.Column3) = 'String'
```

**EDIT:**

For more complex rules on selecting which table has precidence, you can just use CASE statements...

*(This does the same as above, but can be modified for different precidence rules.)*

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN t2.id IS NULL THEN -t1.id      ELSE t2.id      END  AS id,
  CASE WHEN t2.id IS NULL THEN  t1.Column1 ELSE t2.Column1 END  AS Column1,
  CASE WHEN t2.id IS NULL THEN  t1.Column2 ELSE t2.Column2 END  AS Column2
FROM
  Table1          AS t1
FULL OUTER JOIN
  Table2          AS t2
    ON  t1.Column1 = t2.Column2
    AND t1.Column2 = t2.Column2
WHERE
  COALESCE(t2.Column3, t1.Column3) = 'String'
```

Comment: Accord to the example he needs a left join.

Comment: I like the negative id idea. Your query looks interesting, I am gonna try this in a bit.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that there will be no duplicates, then you can boost it by replaceng `UNION` with `UNION ALL` Without the `ALL` the results of the queries will be sorted and the duplicates will be removed when UNIONing. see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Comment: There are duplicates column values. It's stated in the questions towards the end. P.S. Do you mean duplicate record set or duplicate column values?

Comment: Duplicate rows. I.e., all columns between two rows are exactly the same.

Comment: At this point there is none but it is certainly possible in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This should look something like this:

```
SELECT 
    IFNULL(t2.Col1, t1.Col1) Col1,
    IFNULL(t2.Col2, t1.Col2) Col2,
    IFNULL(t2.Col3, t1.Col3) Col3,
    IFNULL(t2.Col4, t1.Col4) Col4,
    'Add this string to the Last Column' 
FROM 
    Table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Column1 = t2.Column1 AND t1.Column2 = t2.Column2
WHERE 
    t1.Column3 ='String'
ORDER BY 
    Col4
```

If table2 columns can have normal NULL values in your database then this SELECT should start like this:

```
SELECT 
    IF(t2.id is NULL, t1.Col1, t2.Col1) Col1,
    IF(t2.id is NULL, t1.Col2, t2.Col2) Col1,
    IF(t2.id is NULL, t1.Col3, t2.Col3) Col1,
    IF(t2.id is NULL, t1.Col4, t2.Col4) Col1,
    'Add this string to the Last Column' 
    .
    .
```

Comment: it could be null and/or any value. Using if doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: @daking963 if your query runs slow, this is not because of IFs, but this means that you are not constructing the best query logic and/or not using the best possible indexes. How many rows this query should return?